# Delete Column table poi java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a workbook template with one sheet and one table with 5 columns.
I want to use the table template(the same style) snd create another table in the same sheet.

I was trying to run this code:

```
XSSFRow row=this.getOutputSheet().getRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colIndexToDelete);
row.removeCell(cell);
```

but the header isn't getting deleted

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround :
First remove the coulmn

table.getCTTable().getTableColumns().removeTableColumn(colIndexToDelete);

Then change the table cell reference (you need to get a reference to your workbook)  :

```
AreaReference reference = workbook.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(
                table.getStartCellReference(), new CellReference(table.getEndCellReference().getRow(), LAST_NEW_COLUMN));

table.setCellReferences(reference);
```